# multiple value followed by computation based on value if then statement

Tags: excel

I am trying to make an excel formula that multiplies a number dependant on multiple values. For example if the value of A1=5 I want to multiple by 1.5 BUT if the value of A1=10 then I want to multiply by 2. I can't seem to get it to do multiple strings, only the first one takes

Comment: Are 1.5 and 10 the only multipliers or do you have more?

Answer (score 0):

Say we want to multiply **B1** by the variable factor, use:

=B1*IF(A1=5,1.5,IF(A1=10,2,1))

Here we assume that if **A1** is neither *5* nor *10,* we multiply by only 1